# discord.py sending message based on a change in api with a get request

Tags: discord.py

so basically I am trying to send a post request to https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users using aiohttp containing user ids which then sends a message in my server with the information it got from the api such as when someone is online on the website i just don't know how to make a post request while sending it to a server and looping it when there's a change on the website

```
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import aiohttp
import asyncio

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Availible")
        
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def check_news():
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
      async with ses.get("https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users") as response:
          if response.status == 200:
              text = await response.text()
              soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
        
       
bot.run("token")
```

i tried different methods other than aio http but i realised its probably not possible without it